# RDP not working with Aetheros AR9565 [168c:0036] (rev01) wifi card in Ubuntu 15:04

Tags: rdp

I have a notebook Acer Aspire E11 E3-112-C4NE, having an Aetheros AR9565 [168c:0036] (rev 01) and I have installed Kubuntu 15.04. On install Kubuntu installs driver ath9k which seems to work properly. 
The situation is the following:

- Acer notebook wifi attaches to a hidden wifi network called PCBDATA, with
  the following parameters:
  IP = 10.139.252.103
  netmask = 255.255.254.0
  gateway = 10.139.252.254
- this laptop can ping another notebook having IP = 10.139.252.102, the 
  rest is the same, and viceversa...
- from this Acer notebook I would like to connect through RDP (using KRDC) 
  to a Windows XP computer with IP = 10.40.138.153 , but after asking 
  for username/password I got an empty window and exits after few seconds

The other notebook can connect to that same XP (10.40.138.154) without any problem through RDP. On the other notebook I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Does anyone has any idea what the problem may be ?

Thanks for help in advance!

Zoltán